# Dynamically add TextFields and Labels on a Combox Event

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, textfield, fxml

I've made an app that works fine but I wan't to add a function and to do so I need to add some TextFields and Label when we change the value of a combobox.
Here is my main code :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;


public class maincombo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/combobox.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
        stage.setTitle("Application");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

}
}
```

My controller :

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;

public class comboboxcontroller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<Integer>methode;
    ObservableList<Integer>nombre = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    @FXML
    private void metho (ActionEvent event){
        switch (methode.getValue()) {
        case 0 :

            break;
        case 1 :
            break;
        case 2 :

            break;
        case 3 :


            break;
        case 4 :

            break;
        case 5 :

            break;
        default :

            break;
        }
    }

    public comboboxcontroller (){

    }


    public void initialize(URL url,ResourceBundle rb){

        nombre.add(new Integer(0));
        nombre.add(new Integer(1));
        nombre.add(new Integer(2));
        nombre.add(new Integer(3));
        nombre.add(new Integer(4));
        nombre.add(new Integer(5));
        methode.setItems(nombre);
    }
}
```

My fxml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="150.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="comboboxcontroller">
   <children>
      <GridPane layoutX="-180.0" layoutY="-205.0" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="20.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <ComboBox fx:id="methode" prefWidth="150.0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </ComboBox>
            <Label text="MyComboBox" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I tried to do something with a switch statement, but it didn't work. What I want is when the user chooses the value 4, then I want it to add 4 labels and Textfields, but if he changes his mind and instead chooses a value of 2 it should show 2 labels and textfields.

**Edit :** I tried to put all my 5 TextFields and Labels and try to hide them with this line :

```
MyTextField.setVisible(false);
```

But everything still visible. So I started to think that maybe it's easier to add them dynamically or maybe with a pop-up window. And that why I here looking for a help.

Comment: Yes but when I don't put any code every body is asking for it and when I put my code nobody want it ! I don't know what could I delete from that code because all I need to make myself clear about the structure of my code. It also show how it's made and can probably help me to add what I want and eventaully improve it. But if you see anything useless here tell me and I'll change it !

Comment: Here it's complete. Take all my code and you'll be able to execute it as I do ! And how can I demonstrate you the fact that I don't know how to do it ? Because it's actully my problem ! I don't have any exception or errors. I just don't know. And all this is related to the problem because I need to add Textfield and Label when I change a choice on my combobox ! Just feel like it's minimal (even if it's a lot I don't know how to reduce it or it will not be executable),complete (don't know what else you need), verifiable (you can see that nothing is happening when changing the value of my combox

Comment: What about that new one ?

Comment: I edit the subject again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar to this a few days ago, check this out:

"Type"-Enum

```
public enum Type {
boObject("BO-Objekt", new Indicator("Test1"), new Indicator("Test2"), new Indicator("Test3")),
job("Job", new Indicator("Test1"), new Indicator("Test2")),
table("Tabelle", new Indicator("Test1")),
tableColumn("Tabellenspalte", new Indicator("Test1"), new Indicator("Test2"));

private String displayName;
private Indicator[] indics;

private Type(String displayName, Indicator ... indics) {
    this.displayName = displayName;
    this.indics = indics;
}

@Override public String toString() {
    return displayName;
}

public Indicator[] getIndics() {
    return indics;
}

public void setIndics(Indicator[] indics) {
    this.indics = indics;
}
}
```

"Indicator"-class:

```
public class Indicator {
private String label;

public Indicator(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}

public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}

public void setLabel(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}
}
```

onAction-Method of Combobox target:

```
@FXML private ComboBox<Type> target;
@FXML private VBox targetBox;   

@FXML public void onTargetSelected() {
    targetBox.getChildren().clear();
    for(Indicator indic : target.getValue().getIndics()) {
        VBox box = new VBox();

        Text t = new Text(indic.getLabel());
        box.getChildren().add(t);

        TextField txt = new TextField();
        txt.setMaxWidth(target.getWidth());
        box.getChildren().add(txt);

        targetBox.getChildren().add(box);
    }
    Controller.stage.close();
    Controller.stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Could you explain more about your "Type-Enum" and "Indicator" class. I don't really understand what is it.

Comment: The Indicator-class defines the Label of the textfield (will be displayed above the textfield).

in the Type-enum you define all possible values of your Combobox. In the constructor you define how many textfield will be displayed along with the selected value (e.g boObject has three textfields)

Comment: So boObjekt, job, table,tableColumn are your differents values available in your ComboBox ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. With "target.getItems().addAll(Arrays.asList(Type.values()));" you can add all values defined to the Combobox ;)